# XSLT on XSD - namespace change

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have a xsd which is transformed with xslt. Based on the original schema, I use the xslt to create a somewhat smaller version to be used by third parties. The xslt works fine for the payload, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a replacement in the namespace.

Id like to replace / expand the namespace from:

`xmlns="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:v1"`

to

`xmlns="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:ekstern:v1"`

and equally for the `targetNamespace`.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    xmlns="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:v1" 
    xmlns:skatt="http://www.skatteetaten.no/xsd" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:v1">
    <xsd:element name="melding" type="Melding"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Melding">
        <!--implemented transformation here is working fine -->
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Desired output (only added :ekstern in namespace)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    xmlns="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:ekstern:v1" 
    xmlns:skatt="http://www.skatteetaten.no/xsd" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:ekstern:v1">
    <xsd:element name="melding" type="Melding"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Melding">
        <!--implemented transformation here is working fine -->
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example of input, your current XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - thank you for answering - see code above. I don't have a current xslt for transforming the xmlns or targetNamespace as I don't find any way to address those keywords. The xslt for the payload is working fine.

Comment: I don't know if that's a good example. The `targetNamespace` in your XML is an *attribute*, not a *namespace*. You should have no problem matching it and replacing its value.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - We can't seem to find out how to match either the "xmlns" nor the "targetNamespace" attribute. That is our question. Any example or guide in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports. Note also that in your example you declare a default namespace using `xmlns="urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:v1"` - but there is no actual node in that namespace. Is that the case in your real implementation? If not, please modify the example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the way that XDM (the XML data model used by XSLT) models namespaces. In particular:

(a) element and attribute nodes have a three-part name comprising prefix, namespace URI, and local name. When you construct an element or attribute node, you need to construct it with the correct three-part name; namespace declarations in the output will then look after themselves. (This rule is usually the only one you need to know. But XSD is a bit different, because namespaces are primarily used in values, not in names, so see (b)).

(b) when namespace prefixes are used in values (for example, in XSD, `type="my:specialType"`) the XSLT processor does not know that `my` here represents a namespace prefix(*), and it's entirely your job to make sure that the result document contains an appropriate binding for this prefix. Typically (in XSLT 2.0+) you will create such a namespace binding using the `xsl:namespace` instruction.

It's also possible to create explicit namespace bindings in XSLT 1.0, provided you have the `exslt:node-set()` extension available, but it's very awkward. Basically the trick is to construct a temporary tree in a variable containing an element with the required namespace prefix and URI, and then (using `xsl:copy` and `exslt:node-set()`) copy the namespace binding from the temporary tree to the final result tree.

This applies to the default namespace binding as much as it does to bindings of explicit prefixes. Explicit prefixes are generally easier to work with than default namespace bindings, and since the final generated XSD will work either way, I'd recommend using explicit prefixes.

(*) unless you happen to be doing a schema-aware XSLT transformation, but I assume that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Micheal is of course right. I made an XSLT that uses `xsl:namespace`. This works for your input just as you wanted, but you might have to adjust it to make it work with the full XSD.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
    <xsl:element name="xsd:schema">
      <xsl:namespace name="" select="'urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:ekstern:v1'" />
      <xsl:namespace name="skatt" select="'http://www.skatteetaten.no/xsd'" />
      <xsl:namespace name="xsd" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />
      <xsl:attribute name="attributeFormDefault">unqualified</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="elementFormDefault">qualified</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="targetNamespace">urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:ekstern:v1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great - thank you! The example works nicely when the xslt is used to transform a given xsd. 
Is there a way to wrap the "xsl:namespace name=""" in a xsl:choose structure or something similar to provide the before - after namespaces for all the xsd's the xslt serves?

`<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=[???] 'urn:something:..'"><xsl:namespace name="" select="urn:something:ekstern..'"/></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><xsl:namespace name="" select="'urn:no:ske:melding:personlig:ekstern:v1'"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>`

Comment: I guess you get better readability if you put this <xsl:choose> inside an <xsl:variable> and you refer to this var from <xsl:namespace>.